# checking duplicates names in email data

Tags: r

I am trying to check duplicates in email data if there are duplicate names with other email.  its working but if there are duplicate with same name then it should reflect all name as duplicate.

so for example if abcd@ddd.com have more than one entries like abcd@ccc.com or abcd@fff.com the all three should reflect as duplicate .

also if abby.del@ddd.com have more than one entries like abby-del@ccc.com or abby_del@fff.com the all three should reflect as duplicate .

```
df <- data.frame(EMP.ID = c(88111,"BBB4477","BBB4058","BBB5832","BBB0338","BBB1814","BBB6543",875430,875970,"BBB0243","BBB1943","BBB9344","BBB9701","BBB1814","BBB8648","BBB4373","BBB7270","BBB6165","BBB7460","BBB7528","BBB6092"),
                 name = c("link adam","dy tt","link adam","gbesada","dojeda","slew lang","?alpucheta","r zona","jachaval","allo nyyn","mbautis","grand fring","jali","kintom dang","namoti","shan mig","NA","NA","NA","NA",NA),
                 email = c("link.adam@gmail.com","dy.tt@abcd.com","link_adam@gmail.com","gbesada@abcd.com","dojeda@abcd.com","?slew.lang@abcd.com","dy-tt@abcd.com","?rzona@abcd.com","jachaval@abcd.com","allo@abcd.com","mbautis@abcd.com","grand.fring@abcd.com","jali@abcd.com","kintom.dang@abcd.com","namoti@abcd.com","shan.mig@abcd.com","mbautis@XYZ.com","?slew.lang@abcd.com",NA,"NA",NA))


separator= " "
valuesToIgnore <- c(NA, NA)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(c(name,email), tolower)) %>% 
  mutate(email_name1 = str_extract(email, "([a-z.]+)(?=@.+)")) %>% 
  mutate(email_name1 = str_replace_all(email_name1, "\\.", separator)) %>% 
  mutate(`13. duplicate name with mailid` = ifelse(duplicated(email_name1, incomparables=valuesToIgnore),"Duplicate email username exists",NA))
```

I have tried many solutions, is there any permanent solution to deal with  email data...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve your problem as follows (note also the change in the regex):

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(name,email), tolower)) %>% 
  mutate(email_name1 = str_extract(email, "([^@]+)@")) %>% 
  mutate(email_name1 = str_replace_all(email_name1, "[\\W_]", "")) %>% %>% 
  group_by(email_name1) %>% 
  mutate(count = n())

# A tibble: 21 x 5
# Groups:   email_name1 [17]
   EMP.ID  name        email                email_name1 count
   <chr>   <chr>       <chr>                <chr>       <int>
 1 88111   link adam   link.adam@gmail.com  link adam       1
 2 BBB4477 dy tt       dy.tt@abcd.com       dy tt           1
 3 BBB4058 link adam   link_adam@gmail.com  adam            1
 4 BBB5832 gbesada     gbesada@abcd.com     gbesada         1
 5 BBB0338 dojeda      dojeda@abcd.com      dojeda          1
 6 BBB1814 slew lang   ?slew.lang@abcd.com  slew lang       2
 7 BBB6543 ?alpucheta  dy-tt@abcd.com       tt              1
 8 875430  r zona      ?rzona@abcd.com      rzona           1
 9 875970  jachaval    jachaval@abcd.com    jachaval        1
10 BBB0243 allo nyyn   allo@abcd.com        allo            1
11 BBB1943 mbautis     mbautis@abcd.com     mbautis         2
12 BBB9344 grand fring grand.fring@abcd.com grand fring     1
13 BBB9701 jali        jali@abcd.com        jali            1
14 BBB1814 kintom dang kintom.dang@abcd.com kintom dang     1
15 BBB8648 namoti      namoti@abcd.com      namoti          1
16 BBB4373 shan mig    shan.mig@abcd.com    shan mig        1
17 BBB7270 na          mbautis@xyz.com      mbautis         2
18 BBB6165 na          ?slew.lang@abcd.com  slew lang       2
19 BBB7460 na          NA                   NA              3
20 BBB7528 na          na                   NA              3
21 BBB6092 NA          NA                   NA              3
```

Note the combination of `group_by` and `mutate`. Here the mutate acts only within the group.

Comment: how I can ignore cases (NA,"") in the code so that it wont give count of NA or "" strings

Comment: Just add a `filter(!is.na(email_name1)` to the steps. If my answer solves your problem, mark it as solution, please.

Comment: i tried the same but this will filter the data , the original data should not change , it should be at it is.

Comment: How about `mutate(count = ifelse(is.na(email_name1), NA, count))`?